# Strange Behaviour of NSTimer

Tags: ios, xcode6, nsdate, nstimer, uidatepicker

> Firstly, this is what I wan't to achieve:

I want to run a `timer` from `Current date and Time` to `user Selected Date and Time`.

> What I have done:

- Made `IBOutlet` of `DatePicker`
- Made one `UIButton`

> What I have tried:

```
- (IBAction)schedulePostTapped:(id)sender
{

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateCountdown:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)updateCountdown:(NSTimer *)timer
{
NSDate *startingDate = [chooseDate date];


NSDate *endingDate = [NSDate date];

double secondsTime = [endingDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startingDate];


NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSUInteger unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:startingDate toDate:endingDate options:0];

NSInteger hours    = [dateComponents hour];
NSInteger minutes  = [dateComponents minute];
NSInteger seconds  = [dateComponents second];
NSString *countdownText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld Hours %ld Minutes %ld Seconds",(long)hours, (long)minutes, (long)seconds];
self.statusLabel.text = countdownText;

NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",secondsTime]);

    if (secondsTime==0) {
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
    }

   }
```

> The issue I'm having:

- Every time I select a time, even one minute after current time, randomly some extra seconds are added to the timer. I am unable to figure it out.

[Example](http://content.screencast.com/users/Dalvik/folders/Jing/media/bfe81804-5aff-4b20-abc4-9c8ca5ccf1cb/00000040.png)

** Delay must be 1m04Sec but it is Showing me 1m55Sec**

Comment: @Zaph See I updated My Question with the LINK

Comment: NSLog the `startingDate` and `endingDate` right after getting the ending date. Manually calculate the difference. Also note that time intervals are in seconds, not miliiseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that modulo 60, -55 is congruent to 5. It seems like the fact that you're doing your calculations backward might be confusing the matter. Look at this:

```
NSDate *startingDate = [chooseDate date];
NSDate *endingDate = [NSDate date];
```

So `endingDate` is the current time when the second line executes, and `startingDate` is the time selected in the picker (which is in the future in your example). When you calculate the difference according to the calendar...

```
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:startingDate toDate:endingDate options:0];
```

it seems that you're getting `-1` for the minutes and `-55` for the seconds. Try turning that around, either by switching the positions of `startingDate` and `endingDate` in the method call above, or by swapping the values that you assign to them. I think that'll lead you to more intuitive results.

Comment: it works... how could i forget this...  but now i am facing a strange problem... my timer sometimes runs sometimes not

Answer (score 1):

Don't have the timer file every second and don't ask for the end time after starting the timer.

Do get the end time from the user and then start the timer with the future date using `initWithFireDate:`. You must add the new timer to a run loop, using addTimer:forMode:. Upon firing, the timer sends the message aSelector to target.

Save the time when they touched the button. Calculate the fire time by adding the selected duration to the saved time.

For documentation add the method call, parameters do not matter, click on `initWithFireDate` and read the documentation in the "Quick Help Inspector"

[image]

Comment: thnx for help...Could You Please tell me by example as i m confused what parameters to pass

Comment: why some extra seconds are added to the code.Is their any way to reslove this

Comment: still i am getting some extra seconds while using your code

Comment: Put some NSLog statements in the code and that should point out the error.